# Accidentally removed python3-dateutil from RHEL 8

Tags: linux, centos, python, operating-systems, redhat-enterprise-linux

I was trying to fix a setup issue related to airflow and accidentally I removed `python3-dateutil` from the machine (RHEL 8) using `sudo yum remove python3-dateutil` this also lead to the removal of  dependant packages like `dnf-plugin-spacewalk`, `dnf-plugins-core`, `rhn-setup`, `rhnsd`, `subscription-manager`, `subscription-manager-cockpit`, `yum-utils` and some various other unused dependencies like `dnf-plugin-subscription-manager`, `rhn-check`, `rhsm-icons`, `subscription-manager-rhsm-certificates`, `usermode` and etc.

Now when I am trying to reinstall `python3-dateutil` using `sudo yum install python3-dateutil`, it's giving **Error: There are no enabled repositories in "/etc/yum.repos.d", "/etc/yum/repos.d", "/etc/distro.repos.d".** None of the yum command is working.

Someone how knows how to fix this issue kindly help.

Comment: Not easy to fix, probably a reinstallation is in order. Python is a core part of the system, removing it also removes most of the tools needed to manage packages.

Answer (score 0):

A very similar question was asked in the post
[CentOS 8 - uninstalled python, How to recover laptop?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1036080/centos-8-uninstalled-python-how-to-recover-laptop)

The answer that was given is as follows:

> You could revert the last transaction with:
>
> ```
> dnf history undo last
> ```
>
> Since you already ran something else, reverting last won't restore to
> the desired state. List the last 5 transactions:
>
> ```
> dnf history list | head -n5
> ```
>
> Then *rollback* to the one *prior* to the ID that corresponds to when
> you mistakenly deleted Python, e.g.:
>
> ```
> dnf history rollback 123
> ```
>
> The `123` should be a transaction that was *before* you deleted
> Python, aka "last good transaction".

Comment: Thanks for the response but I am getting the below error after running "dnf history undo last" command: Error: The following problems occurred while running a transaction:
  Cannot find rpm nevra "python3-dateutil-1:2.6.1-6.el8.noarch".
  Cannot find rpm nevra "subscription-manager-1.28.13-4.el8_4.x86_64".
  Cannot find rpm nevra "subscription-manager-cockpit-1.28.13-4.el8_4.noarch".  Cannot find rpm nevra "usermode-1.113-1.el8.x86_64".
  Cannot find rpm nevra "yum-utils-4.0.18-4.el8.noarch".

Answer (score 0):

1. List the packages you uninstalled using `dnf history|head` + `dnf history info <num>`
2. Open to the [Red Hat Package Browser](https://access.redhat.com/downloads/content/package-browser). And choose your product in the drop-down menu. For me, it is "*Red Hat Enterprise Linux for x86_64*".
3. Search for every package one by one and click "*noarch*" or "*x86_64*" depending on your architecture and package availability.
4. Select the version in the drop-down menu that corresponds to the version you listed in step 1.
5. Download the package (Not the one marked source)
6. Send the RPMs to your server/workstation
7. Run `sudo dnf localinstall *.rpm`